# Restoring an activity stack from a notification?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a notification that create from an activity in a stack, and it's important that the stack be restored. Each activity in the stack should only be there a single time.

So I have this:

`A -> B, B starts notification`

For my intent, I need to restore `A -> B` on the stack. I tried starting A, but the intent didn't seem to have any extras to start `startActivity` immediately.

**What combination of flags and XML attributes do I need to restore a stack?**

If the user is on `B` and taps the notification, it should not start a new stack. Reloading everything is fine, but it should not go `A -> B -> B`.

Comment: If your app is not running when the user taps on the notification, what should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your notification intent use

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Since you can't/shouldn't change the back button function of backing back across different Apps. In `B` activity use an 'Up' button to navigate back up the stack using something like the following

```
Intent upIntent = new Intent(this,ParentActivity.class);
upIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(upIntent);
finish();
```

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` will bring an existing activity to the front, else it will create it keeping the stack free from duplicated activities